# Spring Integration is an alternate to JMS Queues?

Tags: spring-integration

Spring integration is  used to make the communication between two systems easier.
So does that mean the if two systems are talking using JMS queus, then we can remove queues and integrate two systems using Spring Integration Framework?

Answer (score 2):

The main Spring Integration goal is `integration` and JMS is only one way to do that.

If your two systems can get deal with JMS, there is no stops to integrate them using Spring Integration: just provide JMS adapters for both of them.

Further sources to study can be `EIP-book`, `Spring Integration in Action` or the `Reference Manual` from Spring IO site.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding,
Spring Integration solution a framework level solutions to Design Patterns listed in http://eaipatterns.com/

I might be an alternate to ESB which is like one big tunnel & everything passes through that.

Spring Integration provides end to end message between different de-coupled, disparate connecting points.

On the other hand JMS is an API in the Java EE spec which can be used in conjunction with Spring-Integration.
You might as well want to read about AMQP which is a messaging protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Integration is an alternative abstraction to JMS for working with queues. Spring Integration builds on top of other abstractions, [like JMS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jms.html#jms). You need to provide Spring Integration with JMS adapter or some other adapter like [AMQP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp) for it to work.